# Few LotusScript errors

Tags: lotusscript

I am writing agent in LotusScript in Lotus Domino Designer and I get errors in these lines:

```
Dim session As New LCSession
```

Class or Type name not found: LCSESSION.

```
 Dim conn As New LCConnection("db2")
```

Class or Type name not found: LCCONNECTION.
Then:

```
 conn.password = "db2admin"
```

Variable not declared: PASSWORD.

And many similar lines. Where can be the problem, because I am trying to reuse existing code, and I am pretty sure it should work.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell Lotusscript to to load the LotusScript Extensions for Lotus Connectors. So add the following to the (Options) section:

```
Uselsx "*lsxlc"
```

See [the online Domino Designer help](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_971200WORKING_WITH_THE_LSX.html) for more information.